# Yii Widget component cannot find it's view in server

Tags: php, yii

I m new to YII and I have developed a yii app using Eclipse IDE and XAMPP. It perfectly working in windows platform in my local machine. But when I deployed it into server it is not working.

this is my widget controller
"/protected/components/NotificationWidget.php"

```
<?php


class NotificationWidget extends CWidget {public function run() {
    $notifications = Notification::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Date'=>date('Y-m-d')));;

    $this->render('/protected/components/Views/notification.php', array(
        'notifications'=>$notifications   
    ));
}}?>
```

And this is my view

"/protected/components/View"

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
<!-- Menu toggle button --> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i> <span
    class="label label-warning"><?php echo sizeof($notifications);?></span> </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="header">You have <?php echo sizeof($notifications);?>
        notifications</li>
    <li>
        <!-- Inner Menu: contains the notifications -->
        <ul class="menu">
        <?php
        foreach($notifications as $notification) {
            echo "<li>".
    "<a href='#'>".
    " <i class='fa fa-users text-aqua'></i>". $notification->Description.
    "</a></li>";
        }
        ?>
        </ul></li>
    <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a>
    </li>
</ul></li>
```

it gives following error.

> NotificationWidget cannot find the view "/protected/components/Views/notification.php".

can any one help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is unix like check for perfect match form lowercase / Uppercasein your path

```
NotificationWidget cannot find the view "/protected/components/Views/notification.php".
```

I think should by

```
NotificationWidget cannot find the view "/protected/components/views/notification.php".
```

Comment: No same result.cannot find the view.Actually this is the code which is working in my local machine which is not working in the server.

<?php
class NotificationWidget extends CWidget {

    public function run() {
        $notifications = Notification::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Date'=>date('Y-m-d')));;
  
        $this->render(''notification', array(
            'notifications'=>$notifications   
        ));
    }
}
?>

Comment: please update the question and format this code properly. thanks

Comment: `<?php 
class NotificationWidget extends CWidget { 
public function run() { $notifications = Notification::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Date'=>date('Y-m-d')));; $this->render(''notification', array( 'notifications'=>$notifications )); 
} } ?>`

my view name is notification.php under **/protected/components/views**